# showModalDialog() can't see javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, showmodaldialog

***Disclaimer:*** *I understand that showModalDialog() is deprecated, but I don't really have the ability to switch to another method at this time due to technological debt.*

---

I'm currently working on a Struts 1.1 web application and I'm having issues getting the dialog generated by showModalDialog() finding javascript functions. I've tried approaching this from two different angles. First I tried linking the javascript into the JSP that serves as the dialog's content. It doesn't seem to be able to load the javascript. I also tried putting the javascript I need into the javascript file that generates the modal dialog, but this doesn't seem to work either.

Does the dialog generated by showModalDialog have its own scope that can't see anything in the script that generated the dialog? Am I able to link in javascript via the JSP?

---

The following is what the script import in the JSP looks like:

```
<%@ include file="/path/to/file"%>
<%@ page import="com.ex.class%>
<SCRIPT language="Javascript" src="path/to/source" type=text/javascript></SCRIPT>
```

I've already double-checked the path for the script, so I know that it's in the correct place.

Comment: It would be good to show the generated HTML file if possible.

Comment: Turns out I had a bad tag.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a bad tag. Switched it from

```
<SCRIPT language="Javascript" src="path/to/source" type=text/javascript></SCRIPT>
```

to

```
<SCRIPT src="js/merchantTerminal.js" type=text/javascript></SCRIPT>
```

I'm not completely sure as to why this did anything. My guess is that the other one was invalid.